split a tcl string without breaking the proc call
I am trying to call a proc which takes an input variable ie A in this case and compares its value with the ranges given and returns the factor provided along.
I am able to make this work -
get_ranged_factor [get_val A] {0 64 1.02} {64 128 1.05} {128 200 1.1}]
So if value of A is 100, then we see that it is between 64 and 128 and 1.05 is returned.
Now i want the range and factor to be dynamic.
get_factor [get_val A] {0 64 1.02} {64 [get_val B] [get_val C]} {128 200 1.1}]
When I parse this second condition then I am not able to split it into three components ie min should be 64, max should be [get_val B] and factor should be [get_val C].
I used split and lindex but they both split using spaces so they don't work in this case and I get min as 64 and max as [get_val etc.
How should I store min, max, factor correctly so I can work on them in my proc.

Why do you use that get_val command??   That's not built into tclsh.
To get a value of a variable, why not just do $A or set A  ?

You need to use double quotes instead of curly braces so that the command get_val gets evaluated.
get_factor [get_val A] {0 64 1.02} "64 [get_val B] [get_val C]" {128 200 1.1}
For hardcoded lists, it doesn't matter. "0 64 1.02" or {0 64 1.02}
are equivalent.
You could also define your list with the list command.
set a 5
"$a b c"   --> 5 b c
{$a b c}   --> $a b c
[list $a b c]  -->  5 b c


I'd stick with using list instead of double quotes as it's clearer about the intent of the code.

list goes to pretty heavily optimised bytecode.

@DonalFellows At what point does the heavily optimised bytecode make a noticeable runtime improvement?    I did a few benchmarks on my machine and only nanosecond level speed up.

You would notice if you go far enough back; Tcl 7.6 was S...L...O...W... (list's last improvements were in handling of expansion and making it use a literal when all arguments are literals; otherwise, it's just a wrapper round Tcl_NewListObj() and can't really be improved further.)
